# registering custom maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-archetype

How can I register my own Maven archetype, co that other people (in the whole world or just in my local company) might use it?

In Python, there is [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), a global registry where you create packages, upload them, upgrade, ... and you've got a user there which you use to authorize your self.

In node.js, there is [npm](http://npmjs.com), which works exactly the same. There is also bower, which is similar (though it relies on git branches).

Anyway, [this tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes) describes that I can install an archetype locally. But how can I make it public, so that other people may download it? How is it integrated with IDEs (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Publish your archetype (or any other artifact) to the Central Repository via [Sonatype OSS Repository Hosting](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html).

Comment: Won't accept that answer. It just gives a link to a certain hosting, but doesn't explain anything...